# Automatically compile a .au3 script via my C# code

Tags: c#, shell, selenium, batch-file, autoit

I'm trying to compile an .Au3 script code automatically, then then run it. 
I update the script (au3 file) automatically, but for it to work when I update the script, it must be compiled first (to use the new script). 
There is no issue running the .exe file, my issue is I can't find code to compile it before I run it.
This is how I run my executable:

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\Users\XX\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\TESTING TEXT\TESTING TEXT\bin\Debug\XX.exe");
```

But before I run my executable, I need to compile the script.  Any help?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used AutoIt but don't they have a .Net library?   What have you tried so far in attempting to compile an Au3 file?

Comment: Do you really need to compile it? You can use `AutoIt3.exe myScript.au3` to run the script directly (without explicit compiling). [Source](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm)

Comment: Have you got the code, i've never seen that before? Thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this documentation: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/compiler.htm

You should be able to call the command line utility, `Aut2exe.exe`, to compile from another application.

---

The syntax here would be

```
Aut2exe.exe /in c:\path\to\your\script.au3 /out c:\path\to\save\app.exe /icon c:\path\to\icon.ico /x64
```

So to execute this from C#, it would be something like

```
Process.Start('c:\path\to\Aut2exe.exe', '/in c:\path\to\your\script.au3 /out c:\path\to\save\app.exe /icon c:\path\to\icon.ico /x64')
```

Comment: So Do I use C# to execute the code via command line, and it should work?

Comment: You can use virtually any language you want to call an exe to process another file. You could use a batch script if you wanted.

Comment: It appears you would use `Process.start('Aut2exec.exe', '{arguments go here}')`, you may need to make sure the autoit directory that contains that executable is on your PATH in Windows.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm too sure of the arguments I need to use. (im very new)

Comment: @ShawnCoker The link in my answer tells you exactly which arguments the `Aut2exe.exe` program takes and how to use them.

Comment: Sorry for this, but I'm struggling to implement this in my code. I don't have the understanding to implement it? Can you help me in another way? Sorry to trouble you, just not use to all of this.

Comment: @ShawnCoker Check out my edit. This is really simple stuff.

Comment: `Process.Start(@"C:\Users\x\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\TESTING TEXT\TESTING TEXT\bin\Debug\proxyauth.exe', '/in C:\Users\xx\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\TESTING TEXT\TESTING TEXT\bin\Debug\proxyauth.au3 /out C:\Users\Funto\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\TESTING TEXT\TESTING TEXT\bin\Debug\proxyauth.exe /icon C:\Users\xx\Documents\rise\icon.ico /x64'");` This is my code, but it says it can't find it. But thats 100% the location

Comment: @ShawnCoker Why did you replace Aut2exe.exe with your own application? You're trying to _use_ Aut2exe to compile the au3 script. Right now you're passing arguments to an exe file that's not expecting them.

Comment: `Process.Start(@"C:\Users\xx\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\TESTING TEXT\TESTING TEXT\bin\Debug\Aut2exe.exe',` Sorry, I changed it, and it still says it can't locate the file.

Comment: @scilence literally no avail. Been trying since last night.

Comment: @ShawnCoker Because `Aut2exe` is definitely not there. It comes with Autoit. It's probably located in C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\bin.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you another approach. I do the same thing with a Window batch program. It allows to compile AutoIt, prepare a package and generate an installer.

The main step in this Windows batch program are :

- Assign a version number to the application and configure the scripts wich create package and generate Windows installer.
- Compile the application via the main entry point myApplication.au3 with theaut2exe compiler;
- Copy the assets (images, files …) necessary for the proper functioning of the application in the output directory;
- Create a zip archive to recover the application;
- And finally build the installer by compiling the associated InnoSetup script.

All steps, to package the application and generate the installer, can be driven from the Windows batch. You can see documentation here : https://autoit-gui-skeleton.github.io//documentation/creating-setup-package-autoit-application

[image: AGS create setup workflow]

The AutoIt program is compiled from the command line with the **aut2exe** binary. Warning, it is necessary that this last one is to inform in the variable of environment PATH of the operating system.

```
# Set variables
(...)
set AUT2EXE_ARGS=/in "%FOLDER_SRC%\%AUT2EXE_AU3%" /out "%FOLDER_OUT%\%NAME_EXE%" /icon
aut2exe %AUT2EXE_ARGS%
echo Compilation AutoIt is finished.
```

#### AGS Windows batch bandmaster

```
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------
::
::    Copyright © 2018-05
::
::    @name           : AGS-deployment-setup
::    @version        : 1.0.1
::    @AGS package    : AGS v1.0.0
::    @AutoIt version : v3.3.14.5
::    @authors        : 20100 <vb20100bv@gmail.com>
::
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------


cls
@echo off

:: Change value for this variables
set VERSION=0.9.0
set NAME_PROJECT=ApplicationWithCheckForUpdates

:: Deployment variables
set FOLDER_CURRENT=%cd%
set NAME_EXE=%NAME_PROJECT%_v%VERSION%.exe
set FOLDER_SRC=%FOLDER_CURRENT%\..\
cd %FOLDER_SRC%
set FOLDER_SRC=%cd%
set FOLDER_OUT=%FOLDER_CURRENT%\v%VERSION%\%NAME_PROJECT%_v%VERSION%

:: AutoIt compiler
Set AUT2EXE_AU3=ApplicationWithCheckForUpdates.au3
set AUT2EXE_ICON=%FOLDER_SRC%\assets\images\myApplication.ico
set AUT2EXE_ARGS=/in "%FOLDER_SRC%\%AUT2EXE_AU3%" /out "%FOLDER_OUT%\%NAME_EXE%" /icon "%AUT2EXE_ICON%"

:: Path binaries
set ZIP_CLI="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
set ISCC_CLI="C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe"
set ISCC_SCRIPT=AGS-deployment-setup.iss


echo.
echo.
echo      [  AGS-deployment-setup  ]
echo.     
echo.


echo ----[ Variables for generation ]----
echo * VERSION        = %VERSION%
echo * NAME_PROJECT   = %NAME_PROJECT%
echo * FOLDER_CURRENT = %FOLDER_CURRENT%
echo * NAME_EXE       = %NAME_EXE%
echo * FOLDER_SRC     = %FOLDER_SRC%
echo * FOLDER_OUT     = %FOLDER_OUT%
echo * AUT2EXE_ICON   = %AUT2EXE_ICON%
echo * AUT2EXE_AU3    = %AUT2EXE_AU3%
echo * AUT2EXE_ARGS   = %AUT2EXE_ARGS%
echo * ZIP_CLI        = %ZIP_CLI%
echo * ISCC_CLI       = %ISCC_CLI%
echo * ISCC_SCRIPT    = %ISCC_SCRIPT%
echo -------------------------------------

echo.
echo.

echo ----[ Step 1/7 - Creating directories ]----
cd %FOLDER_CURRENT%
echo * Attempt to create : "%cd%\v%VERSION%\"
mkdir v%VERSION%
cd v%VERSION%
echo.
echo * Attempt to create : %cd%\%NAME_PROJECT%_v%VERSION%\
mkdir %NAME_PROJECT%_v%VERSION%
cd %FOLDER_CURRENT%
echo -------------------------------------

echo.
echo.


echo ----[ Step 2/7 - Launch AutoIt compilation ]----
echo * Run compilation with aut2exe and AUT2EXE_ARGS.
aut2exe %AUT2EXE_ARGS%
echo * Compilation AutoIt is finished.
echo -------------------------------------

echo.
echo.


echo ----[ Step 3/7 - Copy assets files ]----
echo * Create the file xcopy_EXCLUDE.txt in order to ignore some file and directory.
echo .au3 > xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo /releases/ >> xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo /src/ >> xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo /vendor/ >> xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo *   - ignore all .au3 files
echo *   - ignore all .pspimage files
echo * The file xcopy_EXCLUDE.txt is created.
echo.
echo * Copy additional files store in assets, config, docs directories
xcopy "%FOLDER_SRC%\assets" "%FOLDER_OUT%\assets\" /E /H /Y /EXCLUDE:xcopy_Exclude.txt
xcopy "%FOLDER_SRC%\config" "%FOLDER_OUT%\config\" /E /H /Y /EXCLUDE:xcopy_Exclude.txt
xcopy "%FOLDER_SRC%\docs" "%FOLDER_OUT%\docs\" /E /H /Y /EXCLUDE:xcopy_Exclude.txt
@copy "%FOLDER_SRC%\package.json" "%FOLDER_OUT%\package.json" /Y > log
echo "%FOLDER_SRC%\package.json" is copied.
@copy "%FOLDER_SRC%\README.md" "%FOLDER_OUT%\README.md" /Y > log
echo "%FOLDER_SRC%\README.md" is copied.
echo * Ok all files and directory are copied.
echo.
echo * Delete xcopy_Exclude.txt.
del xcopy_Exclude.txt
del log
echo -------------------------------------

echo.
echo.


echo ----[ Step 4/7 - Create additional files ]----
echo * Create file ".v%VERSION%" in FOLDER_OUT.
cd %FOLDER_OUT%
echo Last compilation of application %NAME_PROJECT% version %VERSION% the %date% at %time% > .v%VERSION%
echo * This file has been created.
echo -------------------------------------

echo.
echo.


echo ----[ Step 5/7 - Create zip archive ]----
echo * Move in the folder %FOLDER_CURRENT%\v%VERSION%
cd %FOLDER_CURRENT%\v%VERSION%
echo * Zip the folder %NAME_PROJECT%_v%VERSION%
%ZIP_CLI% a -tzip %NAME_PROJECT%_v%VERSION%.zip "%NAME_PROJECT%_v%VERSION%
echo * The zip has been created.
echo -------------------------------------

echo.
echo.

echo ----[ Step 6/7 - Make setup with InnoSetup command line compilation ]----
cd %FOLDER_CURRENT%
echo * Launch compilation with iscc
%ISCC_CLI% %ISCC_SCRIPT% /dApplicationVersion=%VERSION% /dApplicationName=%NAME_PROJECT%
echo.
echo * Compilation has been finished.
echo -------------------------------------

echo.
echo.

echo ----[ Step 7/7 - Delete temp folder use for ISS compilation ]----
cd %FOLDER_CURRENT%
echo * Delete the folder %FOLDER_CURRENT%\v%VERSION%\%NAME_PROJECT%_v%VERSION%\
rmdir %FOLDER_CURRENT%\v%VERSION%\%NAME_PROJECT%_v%VERSION% /S /Q
echo -------------------------------------

echo.
echo.

cd %FOLDER_CURRENT%
echo ----[ End process ]----
echo.
```